# check if array is alrdeady FULLY filled with any non-default value

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am not sure if it's rly possible to check but I have an issue rn where I have an array

let's say: `int[] unmarkedSum = new int[100];`

Now I put something in this array when a certain condition is true so not in every single iteration. But I know for a fact that at some point the whole array will be filled with any positive values that are not 0 because of how my algorithm works.

My question here is: Is there a way of checking WHEN it's fully filled?

Like I started like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < unmarkedSum.length; i++) {
    if(unmarkedSum[i] == 0 {
        break; 
    }
    else {
        // idk tbh 
    }
}
```

Comment: you can share this array with another thread so that one thread can fill the values and another can check the array at the same time. When second thread finds that there's no any default values (or 0s) then it can notify to the first thread (or the main thread)

Comment: Haven't worked with threads yet but still thanks for that solution.

Comment: @VipulVerma that sounds needlessly complex.

Answer (score 1):

In **Java** by default an array of `int`s is filled with zeros. You can use this to check if the array is fully filled. For example you can create a method which checks for 0 and returns true if there are no 0:

```
public static bool isArrayFilled(int[] array) {
    for(int i = array.length; i >= 0; i--){
        if(array[i] == 0) {
            return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
}
```

If array is big enough and filled out of order, you can use [advanced algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-algorithms/) to find at least one 0 value in the array.

Comment: This doesn't work but it's not your bad. Forgot to mention that the array gets filled randomly. So it can first fill the 13th entry and then after maybe the 74th and so on until it is fully filled with any positive numbers that aren't 0.

Comment: what do you mean by "fully filled"? if you mean that non of the items of array would be zero than those method should work, you just need to pass the array `unmarkedSum` to those method: `bool isFilled = isArrayFilled(unmarkedSum)`

Comment: Omg yh I mixed sth up. It does actually work ^^ sry

Comment: @EgZoShift did you try the code from my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply maintain a variable size that keep tracks of how many values have been written to the array.

Example:

```
        int size = 0;
        int[] array = new int[100];
        Random r = new Random();
        while(size < array.length){
            int index = r.nextInt(100);
            int val = r.nextInt(1000)+500;
            if (array[index] == 0){
              array[index] = val;
              size++;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my previous comment, you can share this array with another thread so that one thread can fill the values and another can check the array at the same time. When the second thread finds that there are no default values (or 0s) then it can notify the first thread (or the main thread). Here is how you can do that

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class CheckArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        var arr = new int[50];

        Thread arrayChecker = new Thread(() -> {
            var isZeroPresent = false;
            while (true) {
                for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
                    isZeroPresent = false;
                    if (arr[index] == 0) {
                        isZeroPresent = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isZeroPresent == false) {

                    // if the for loop completed then control will come here
                    System.out.println("Array has been filled");
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
        arrayChecker.start();
        
        // fill random values in the array
        // while another thread has been started
        Random random = new Random(); 
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            
            int index = random.nextInt(arr.length);
            arr[index] = random.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
        
    }


}
```

Comment: Using threads directly is anachronistic, and a busy `while (true)`-loop is pretty much never a good idea, and neither is `Thread.sleep ()`. The principle is kind of sound, I'd suggest using `CompletableFuture` though.